# python call method of specified base class

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

Is it possible in python to call a method from a *specific* class in hierarchy?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Base:
    def f1( self ):
        print("f1 from Base")

class Derived ( Base ):
    def f1( self ):
        print("f1 from Derived")

class Derived2 ( Derived ):
    def f1( self ):
        print("f2 from Derived2")
        super( ).f1()


d2 = Derived2()
d2.f1()
```

Using `super` calls ever the next higher one. Can I also write it so that derived class method `f1` will call `f1` from Base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know what the class is called (`Base` in this case) you can call its methods directly:

```
class Derived2(Derived):
    def f1(self):
        print("f2 from Derived2")
        Base.f1(self)
```

if you need to go deeper in the *method resolution order*, you can mess with [`Derived2.__mro__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) (this calls the first child of `object`):

```
 class Derived2(Derived):
    def f1(self):
        print("f2 from Derived2")
        Derived2.__mro__[-2].f1(self)
```